# What does this mean in c? square brackets inside curly brackets

Tags: c

```
const int status[STATUS_SIZE] = {
        [0] = -1, 
        [1] = 0,
        [2] = 1,
};
```

and

```
const char *messages[MESSAGE_SIZE] = {
        [0] = "OK",
        [1] = "NG",
};
```

Can you explain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C99 introduces [Designated Initializers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html#Designated-Inits), with which you can initialize an array
in any order by using the index.

> *[6.27 Designated Initializers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html#Designated-Inits)*
>
> Standard C90 requires the elements of an initializer to appear in a fixed order, the same as the order of the elements in the array or structure being initialized.
>
> In ISO C99 you can give the elements in any order, specifying the array indices or structure field names they apply to, and GNU C allows this as an extension in C90 mode as well. This extension is not implemented in GNU C++.
>
> To specify an array index, write `[index] =` before the element value. For example,
>
> ```
> int a[6] = { [4] = 29, [2] = 15 };
> ```
>
> is equivalent to
>
> ```
> int a[6] = { 0, 0, 15, 0, 29, 0 };
> ```